# Duplicate objects in AD and ADC (hybrid environment)

Tags: active-directory, entra-id, azureadconnect

We are managing a migration to Office 365.
I have therefore configured a server with a DC role and one with the Azure AD Connect component.

Some users had already been enrolled in Azure AD to take advantage of Office 365 licenses, while the others I had previously added locally in the DC.
After the last synchronization, I find duplicates in Azure and I don't know how to manage them.

For Example:
On DC - User: Paolino Paperino, account:Paolino.paperino@contoso.com, mail: Paolino.paperino@contoso.com
ON Azure - User: Paolino Paperino, account: paolino.paperino@contoso.com, mail: -
ON Azure ( duplicate ? ) - User: Paolino Paperino, account: paolino.paperino@contoso.onmicrosoft.com, mail: paolino.paperino@contoso.onmicrosoft.com

How could I solve this problem to combine the two users? Should I delete the user in Azure and create an alias in the one synchronized by AD?

In addition, I am notified of the "warning" that for some users the proxyAddresses field is empty. Can I directly enter the smtp alias fields in AD?

Thank you all.

Alf

Comment: Check this out, it should address the most comment sync issues: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/azure/active-directory/objects-dont-sync-ad-sync-tool